# C program - Dereference pointer

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, fgets

I am new to C and am trying to run a few lines of code while there is user input. For some reason, I am getting an error at this line:

```
char names[SIZE][LENGTH];    
while(fgets(names, LENGTH, stdin) != '\0')
```

The error is: "Multiple markers at this line. Comparison between pointer and zero character constant. Did you mean to dereference the pointer? Passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a good C book

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are going to read lines into elements of a two-dimensional array.

From the C Standard (7.21.7.2 The fgets function)

> 3 The fgets function returns s if successful. **If end-of-file is
>   encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the
>   contents of the array remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned.
>   If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are
>   indeterminate and a null pointer is returned.**

Thus a correct loop can look like

```
size_t i = 0;
while( i < SIZE && fgets(names[i], LENGTH, stdin) != NULL)
{
    //...
    ++i;
}
```

Or if you are going to stop reading lines when an empty line was encounterd then you can write

```
size_t i = 0;
while( i < SIZE && fgets(names[i], LENGTH, stdin) != NULL && names[i][0] != '\n' )
{
    //...
    ++i;
}
```

The error messages that your compiler issued means the following

> Passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type.

In this function call

```
fgets(names, LENGTH, stdin)
```

the expression `names` used as the first argument has type `char ( * )[LENGTH]` but the function expects an argument of the type `char *`
.

> "Comparison between pointer and zero
>   character constant. Did you mean to dereference the pointer?

This message means that the compiler can not conclude whether the returned by the function pointer is compared with a null-pointer or you was going to compare the character pointed to by the returned pointer with the character `'\0'`.

Comment: I tried using NULL, however, I get the error: passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type